# Can I have a Google form that allows users to upload documents but does not require a Google account?

Tags: google-account, google-forms, google-account-profile

I have a Google form that is requiring users (survey takers) to have a Google account to access the form. This form includes sections that require the user to upload files before they can submit.

We have "restricted to xxx domain" and "limit to 1 response" (and all other boxes in the settings/gear icon section) *unchecked*.

Why is it still requiring a Google log in?

Comment: @user0 Forms is a product, hence why I made that word a proper noun.

Answer (score 1):

The file upload question requires that the respondent is signed in by using a Google account.

One alternative is to use Google Apps Script to create a web application that run as you but you should create your form by using HTML/CSS/JavaScript.